# Make Subscriptions available in Google PlayStore

Tags: xamarin.forms, google-play

I am using [InAppBilling](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/InAppBillingPlugin) plugin in a Xamarin.Forms solution.
IAP works in iOS and the app is approved and ready to release.

HOWEVER, I'm having issues getting this to work with the Google PlayStore.

The PlayStore returns the message: `[productSKU] does not exist`.
But that subscription item is clearly in the PlayStore AND activated with the exact SKU I'm using.

Does anyone know why a subscription item cannot be found or reached?

And yes, I've double checked and triple checked that the right SKU was being passed in in this:

`var purchase = await billing.PurchaseAsync(**productId**, ItemType.Subscription, verify);`

Is there any other obscure setting in the PlayStore that would cause this item to not be found?

Answer (score 0):

After digging through docs and getting this working, here are some tips for those who could do with some help.

Upload your signed .apk or app bundle to the PlayStore in Closed Testing.
Submit for review. May take a few days (3 days for mine).
Promote the approved app to the Alpha track and you probably have [yourapp] Track1 too.
Setup you IAPs and activate.
Set you app as "Published" in Advanced Settings. This will trigger a review but it should be quick if the app has already been reviewed.

You CANNOT test AIPs from debug mode. You need to build in release and sign, then deploy to testing device THEN try purchase your item(s).

If I figure out how to step through in debug mode, I'll see if I can add to this later.